# How to add a column containing mean value to a table in SAS

Tags: merge, sas

Assume this is my dataset:

```
data test;
   input  Age ;
   datalines;
34 
28 
27 
36 
32 
39 
12 
32 
;
```

How can I add a column to this dataset which contains the average value of the age column?

Comment: You can also use proc means/summary/univariate and merge the data back in. This question has an example but uses total instead of mean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578100/making-the-proc-means-statement-in-sas-produce-a-variable-instead-of-a-dataset/33578631#33578631

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PROC SQL;

```
proc sql;
create table test2 as
select age, 
       mean(age) as age_mean
from test;
quit;
```

Without a GROUP BY statement, SQL will merge the mean back with the original values.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out myself

Comment: You can use the * wild card to get all original values in the data set.  You will need to add a "mean(<var>)" for each variable you want the mean calculated.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to get it with proc sql.

```
proc sql;
   select *,mean(age) as Age_mean from test;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.